# Tryparse not working for me and ParseExact works but it fails when extra space is included

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, tryparse

Tryparse not working for me and ParseExact works but it fails when extra space is included:

```
//Tryparse
string dateTimeString = "Sep 10 08:19";
DateTime dateAndTime;

if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dateAndTime))
{
    string temp = dateAndTime.ToString();   //"9/21/2018 10:08:00 AM" ??????? why?
}

//ParseExact works fine but it won't work with extra spaces in the date
string format = "MMM d HH:mm";
//dateTimeString = "Sep 10 08:19"; //works fine with this string
dateTimeString   = "Sep  9 08:19"; //notice extra extra space between "Sep" and "9"
dateAndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); //Exception here
string temp2 = dateAndTime.ToString();
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first thing is you should use `TryParseExact()` instead of `ParseExact()` since that is the right comparable method to `TryParse()`.

Next you just need to pass in an extra parameter to your method, The [`DateTimeStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=netframework-4.7.2) value `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces`:

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(
   "Sep 10 08:19", 
   "MMM d HH:mm", 
   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
   DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, 
   out dateAndTime))
{
    //Parsed correctly, do something
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8GZwft)

Comment: thanks man. I can also see I can pass string[] formats. Array of formats? I will try your method. Didn't even noticed the method you suggested. Always humble and learning from you guys. Thanks!

Comment: @Max yeah an array of formats.  For your case here its better to use `DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces` but its something to keep in mind for future issues